# how to open a pdf file in a popup window with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code throws a JS error, offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll. I tried `position: relative;` but it still shows the same error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnShow').click(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        }); 
    });                  
</script>

<a href="#" id="trigger">this link</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none; position: relative; height: 4em; overflow: scroll;">
    <div>
        <iframe src="reports/my_pdf.pdf"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: help-eth . this thing is not going away ...

Comment: are you sure offsetParent is even in the code you working with.... see if you get that without any of the code in your example. also take the styles off your dialog div...

Comment: @Seabizkit, loading pdf to iframe inside hidden div is enough to get that (at least in firefox), also you are right - style "display: none" for dialog div is enough.

Comment: i just had to put this one window.open("reports/my_pdf.pdf", "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use "lazy loading":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnShow').click(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog();
            $("#frame").attr("src", "reports/my_pdf.pdf");
        }); 
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="btnShow">this link</a>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the following error: `$(...).dialog is not a function`

Comment: @Pathros, jQuery UI library has dialog widget: jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than jquery you can simply do this by using Javascript

You can use `window.open()` method and insert the pdf file in it `window.open("path/for/pdffile")` and give width, height and its position

```
window.open("path/for/pdffile", "width=500,height=500,top=100,left=500")
```

You can insert the above code in a function and call it when a html element is clicked .

That's it your pdf file will be opened in a pop up window

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to open it with a pop-up window? something small inside the same page.